# C++ SML 2.5 / Entities managing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, game-physics, sfml

Im currently on a school project and i do not have any ideas to do what I really want to do cause Im a beginner on it. First of all im using SFML 2.5 and that is the problem.

The problem.

I have to create an aquarium with fishes inside of it. I followed the tuto on the net and I finally create an aquarium with one entity which is moving and detecting colision thanks to the TileMap. The problem is that I have to create an Entity on everyclick by the player. Im using a factory and an abstractEntity to create and draw the entity

I've see on internet that we can create a pool of entities with creation and destruction management. I've tried to do that but the result is not here. Can someone help me. Do not hesitate to ask me to share code or informations.

There is an other way to spawn same entities than a pool?

My fish entity

```
class Fish : public Character
{
public:
    Fish();
    ~Fish();
    Fish* getNext() const { return state_.next; }
    void setNext(Fish* next) { state_.next = next; }


    void move();
    bool inUse() const { return framesLeft_ > 0; }

private:
    int framesLeft_;
    union
    {
        // State when it's in use.
        struct
        {
            double x, y;
            double xVel, yVel;
        } live;

    // State when it's available.
    Fish* next;
    } state_;
};
```

My pool entity

```
    class FishPool
{
public:
explicit FishPool(void) :
    m_entities(new Fish[POOL_SIZE])
    m_firstAvailable(nullptr) {
    // Assign first available entity.
    m_firstAvailable = m_entities[0];

    // Assign each entity's next pointer.
    for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE - 1; ++i) {
        m_entities[i].setNext(&m_entities[i + 1]);
    }

    // Terminate end of array.
    m_entities[POOL_SIZE - 1].setNext(nullptr);
}

~FishPool(void) {
    delete[] m_entities;
}

Fish* create(void) {
    // Check if pool is full.
    //assert(m_firstAvailable != nullptr);

    // Pull out the next available entity.
    Fish* e = m_firstAvailable;
    m_firstAvailable = e->getNext();

    // Init entity if needed...
    // ...

    return e;
}

void destroy(Fish* e) {
    // Reset entity data...
    // ...

    e->setNext(m_firstAvailable);
    m_firstAvailable = e;
}

private:
static const int POOL_SIZE = 100;
Fish m_entities[POOL_SIZE];
Fish m_firstAvailable;
};
```

My loop game

```
// Boucle de jeu
while (window.isOpen()) {
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
        

        /*switch (event.type) {
        case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
            // Ajout d'un point fish
            scores.AddPoint(1); 
            // Ajout d'un point algues
            scores.AddPointAlg(1);
            // La creation de poisson

            if (!tileFish.move("images/fish.png", sf::Vector2u(32, 32), fish.GetX(), fish.GetY()))
                return -1;
            break;
        case sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased:
            //
            break;
        }*/
        
    }
        
        sf::Time delta_time = sf::milliseconds(100);

        instance.Update();
        elapsed_time += r.restart();
        
        // Update/Refresh frequency
        float f = fps.getFps(instance);
        
        

        if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
        {
            factory.Create("fish");
        }
        else {
            // We have enough time to spawn a sprite. ( may be for several ? )
            while (elapsed_time >= delta_time) {
                // Spawn your sprite
                // ...
                /*if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
                {
                    if (!tileFish.create("images/fish.png", sf::Vector2u(32, 32), fish.GetX(), 
 fish.GetY()))
                        return -1;
                }*/
                if (!tileFish.move(imageFish, sf::Vector2u(32, 32), fish.GetX(), fish.GetY()))
                    return -1;
                fish.move();
                //dory.move();
                // Substract the time consumed
                elapsed_time -= delta_time;
            }
        }

        

        window.clear();
        window.draw(tileMap);
        window.draw(tileFish);
        map.drawText(window, scores.GetScores(), scores.GetScoresAlg(), instance.GetStartedTime(), 
f);
        window.display();
    }
return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your `FishPool` class seems unnecessarily complicated and also broken (does it even compile?). Why don't you just use a `std::vector<Fish>`? Then adding and removing entities from it would be trivial

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. No the FishPool is clearly not necesserrarly, im just trying to find a solution. Could you explain me a bit more the `std::vector<Fish>` ? I mean how to remove and add entities from it?

Comment: There isn't really much to explain for `std::vector` (best to read the documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It's a dynamically resizing array, so you can just add new elements to it via `push_back`(and remove existing ones via `erase` or `std::erase_if`), which seems to be exactly what you want to do